# How to compare two data frames in Pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark

```
c = df[df['CUSTOMER_EMAIL_ID'].isin(d.CUSTOMER_EMAIL_ID)]
```

How to write same expression in PySpark?

Comment: what you want to do ? can you explain in more details ? do you want to compare or check exists or not?

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking "give me all the rows from `df` where the `CUSTOMER_EMAIL_ID` field has a matching value from the `CUSTOMER_EMAIL_ID` field in `d`", then I think your question can be answered using a [semi join](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Semijoin_.28.E2.8B.89.29.28.E2.8B.8A.29), specifically:

```
c = df.join(b, 'CUSTOMER_EMAIL_ID', 'leftsemi')
```

A left (right) semi join can be thought of conceptually as a inner join followed by dropping the right (left) columns.